# Ruby on rails google wallet

Tags: android-pay

how to implement Google wallet with ruby on rails? I searched lot but did not get any doc. please help me. Thanks

I visited several links
1: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial

Comment: Don't you think the link you provided has given you enough example (server side)

Comment: ya but i am little bit confused in jws integration so i asked.

Comment: How about this [link to available libraries](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/libraries)?

Comment: it is just about json web token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't have a sample in Ruby for Digital Goods, but we have one for Instant Buy that might be helpful
https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/instant-buy/web/quickstart-ruby

Also take a look at the JWT Ruby Library
https://github.com/progrium/ruby-jwt

We also have a link to a JWT decoder that will be helpful when testing your app. You can find it in the Digital Goods doc site under Resources --> Tools --> JWT Decoder

Comment: thanks a lot maru ahues :)

Comment: The first link isn't working for me. Can you please help?